Returning additional values from scipy.odeint
I want to solve an ordinary differential equation in Python using scipy.odeint while returning some values from a defined function, which are not differentials.
I tried storing the additional values in a list, which should give me the result. The problem is, that the additional value is added every iteration step and thus my list has stored a lot more values than it shouldin the end.
I added a code example of my problem:
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

# Define the ODE function
def model(y, t):
    dydt = -2 * y
    x = np.random.rand(1,1) # Adds a random number as a dummy
    addtional_value.append(x)
    return dydt

# Initial condition
y0 = 5

# Defin an empty list
addtional_value = []

# Time points at which the solution is computed
t = np.arange(0, 5, 1)

# Solve the ODE
y = odeint(model, y0, t)

print(len(y))
5
print(len(addtional_value))
151


You could define you model as a class with a __call__ method that will be used by the ODE solver, and store your additional information as a class attribute. E.g.,
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

# Define the ODE function
class MyModel:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = None

    def __call__(self, y, t):
        """
        This method will be used by the ODE solver.
        """

        dydt = -2 * y
        x = np.random.rand(1,1) # Adds a random number as a dummy

        self.x = x  # store x as class attribute

        return dydt
    
y0 = 5

# Time points at which the solution is computed
t = np.arange(0, 5, 1)

model = MyModel()  # create class instance

# Solve the ODE
y = odeint(model, y0, t)

# have a look at what's in x
print(model.x)
[[0.22605118]]


I try to avoid using a class, becase it makes my calculation unnecessary complicated.

Using a class and storing things as class attributes is generally better than using global variables. What unnecessary complications does using a class create (other than slightly longer code)?

Longer code was the reason for my statement, but you are probably right. I tried to solve my problem with a global variable, but it didn't work somehow. Might have made a mistake.
